# escape colon in Xpath search

Tags: xpath, selenium, hpricot

I'm using Hpricot with selenium I have this html input element:

```
<input id="foo:bar"/>
```

And I'm trying to get this value with this Xpath expression:

```
source = Hpricot(@selenium.get_html_source)
source.search("//input[@id='foo:bar']")
```

but it is not finding anything because of the colon. I have seen that the Xpath expression cannot contain any colon. I have tried to escape it in different ways but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to escape it or avoid this problem? I cannot change the values in the html so the foo:bar has to be this way, with the colon. But I need to find this element somehow.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use XPath for this locator, as long as the `id` is unique you can simply use:

```
id=foo:bar
```

Even then, the `id=` prefix is not necessary as it will be assumed by default.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and the other solutions proposed here didn’t work for me, so used [get_element_by_id](http://rdoc.info/github/hpricot/hpricot/Hpricot/Container/Trav%3aget_element_by_id).

So basically:

```
source = Hpricot(@selenium.get_html_source)
source.get_element_by_id("foo:bar")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve this with a css locator, and specify that the id contains a particular string (the fact this is matching a string should remove any weirdness caused by the colon).
This locator worked for me when I tried it in Selenium IDE:

```
css=input[id:contains('foo:bar')]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with hpricot, so couldn't tell you how to convert into the appropriate syntax for that, but it does appear to support CSS locators.

Comment: I was seeing in the HPricot documentation that you can use either a XPath expression or css locator. I was trying your suggestion but it didn't work, not sure if it was my mistake though, I'm new with xpath and selenium.. I found a workaround so I can get get the unique element with the second part of the id + other attribute. thanks